# How to fixed array problem in Codeigniter framework?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

[image: it the prespcription table,here you see medicine_id column can not get 3 inputs from dropdown menus][image: here select the dropdown value]

I am a beginner of CodeIgniter. I have some issues in arrays.
I have 3 dropdown menus to select a medicine that is fetched through the medicine database. but I don't understand how to put 3 values in one field of the table. 
there are two tables:

1. Medicine table(medicine_id ,medicine_name)
2. Prescription table(prescription_id,patient_id,symptoms,disgonis,medicine_id,m_note,date)

How to put multiple values in a medicine_id column?

Comment: Don't do that, you will only end in trouble. Have a look at database normalization first

Comment: can you please elaborate?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Have you looked up what database normalization is, and why that helps you to get a good database scheme?

Comment: Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574/8566549) so you could decide better on what's the best data storing option for you

Answer (score 2):

you cant put multiple values into one column in mysql. You got a so called 1:n relation here. 1 Prescription can have n medicines.

For representing that relation in mysql you need to create a new table

Prescription_Medicine(prescription_id,medicine_id)

where you have one row for every medicine thats on the prescription. You should get a quick overview over database normalization as the commenters suggested.

Answer (score 2):

First Approach: **Not Recommended**

You can set the medicine_id field as varchar and save all medicine id in comma separated form. When you need to join Prescription table to Medicine table you have to user FIND_IN_SET.
But it is **not recommended** because it is against normalization rules. and it will slow down your execution.

Second Approach:

You can make another table, where you will store prescription_id and medicine_id. As @Sam Tigle told you.

Answer (score 1):

You can save an array into a database field in different ways

1. Serialized form
2. Comma-Separated string
3. JSON
   (Read more about JSON data type [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html))

> **But it is not the proper solution for your problem**. You should consider a workaround as given below:

Usually, a single prescription can have multiple medicines. Therefore a **One to Many** relation is there.

It is recommended that you create two tables as `prescriptions` and `prescription_medicines`, and save the `prescription` details in the `prescriptions` table and then add each `medicine` in a `prescription` as a row in the  `prescription_medicines` table.

The table structure can be something as shown below.

`prescriptions` table

```
id (primary_key), doctor_id, patient_i`, date, .....
```

`prescription_medicines` table

```
id, prescription_id, medicine_id, dosage, ...
```

Here the `prescription_id` is the `primary_key` of `prescriptions_table`
and the `medicine_id` should be a `primary_key` of `medicines_table`

Now we can relate the prescriptions with medicines table.

EXAMPLE QUERY: To get the prescribed medicines and its dosage for a patient having patient id 123

```
SELECT med.name, pres_med.dosage 
FROM prescriptions AS pres
JOIN prescription_medicines AS pres_med ON pres_med.prescription_id = pres.id
JOIN medicines AS med ON med.id = pres_med.medicine_id
WHERE pres.patient_id = 123;
-- ADD YOUR OWN LOGIC TO GET THE LASTEST/RELEVANT PRESCRIPTION
```